# My timepicker addon uses the wrong timezone

Tags: laravel, momentjs, jquerydatetimepicker

I have added a timepicker to my datepicker. Everything works, but when I posts, the time will degrees by 2 hours (I think it somthing in moment js).

Does someone know this problem and know how to fix it?

[image: It shows the timezone]

The datetime that I inserted was `2018-10-09 09:00` to `2018-10-09-12:00`.

Comment: show me code when you define your date on `moment js`

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos:
dayClick (mom) { //, jsEvent, view
                EventBus.emit('populate-event-modal', {
                    start: mom.add(7, 'hours'), end: mom.clone().add(1, 'hours')
                });
            },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Application Timezone in your `config/app` file.

Example for me:

```php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
```

Comment: no that is not the problem. i think it is somthing in momen js.

Comment: self.$emit('update', moment(dateString, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
the problem is in here. but i dont know how to fix it